# Which scriptures should be suffixed with the term Samhita?

Tags: scripture, terminology, samhita

According to the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samhita)

> Samhita literally means "put together, joined, union", a "collection",
> and "**a methodically, rule-based combination of text or verses**".
> Samhita also refers to the most ancient layer of text in the Vedas,
> consisting of mantras, hymns, prayers, litanies and benedictions.
>
> Parts of Vedic Samhitas constitute the oldest living part of Hindu
> tradition.

It says that some rule based combination are called Samhitas. If yes, what are the rules?

We generally say RigVeds Samhita, but not Mahabharata Sahmita or Ramayana Samhitha.

What is the eligibility for a text to be called as Samhita?